# Having a Action Text (Trix & Rich text content) in an textarea HTML?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to add an Action Text editor in my website.
The installation went smoothly and it works in a classic content div.

[Website example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d41Wa.png)

View code :

```
<div class="article-code" data-controller="clipboard" data-clipboard-success-content="Copied !">
            <div class="article-code-content">
              <textarea class="trix-content" readonly data-clipboard-target="source" rows="5" type="text"><%= article.content.to_plain_text%></textarea>
            </div>
            <div type="image" class="card-copy" data-action="clipboard#copy">
              <button class="btn-copy" type="button" data-action="clipboard#copy" data-clipboard-target="button">Copy</button>
            </div>
          </div>
```

You can see it on the above image :

- On the first div content the italic & bold styles are working
- However, on the second div which is an textarea type, the styles are not working

I'm using a textarea tag to be able to add a clipboard controller, but it seems that this textarea tag is causing the problem regarding the text styles.

Is there anyway to add the styles, and keeping the clipboard feature ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where are you coming up with `type="image"`? There is no such attribute in HTML. I'm not sure some of your other types exist either.

Comment: Agreed the type image is a wrong one ! 
Regarding the type = "button" I used the same ones provided in the Stimulus / Clipboard documentation : https://www.stimulus-components.com/docs/stimulus-clipboard/